# error in C++, within context

Tags: c++, inheritance

I received homework to make program without casting using constructors so this is my code, I have two classes:

```
class Base {
protected:
    int var;
public:
    Base(int var = 0);
    Base(const Base&);
    Base& operator=(const Base&);
    virtual ~Base(){};
    virtual void foo();
    void foo() const;
    operator int();
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived(int var): Base(var){};
    Derived(const Base&);
    Derived&  Derived::operator=(const Base& base);
    ~Derived(){};
    virtual void foo();
};
```

here two of my functions of Derived:

```
Derived::Derived(const Base& base){
    if (this != &base){
        var=base.var;
    }
}

Derived&  Derived::operator=(const Base& base){
    if (this != &base){
        var=base.var;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

but I have an error `within context` when I call these rows

```
Base base(5);
Base *pderived = new Derived(base);  //this row works perfectly
Derived derived = *pderived;  // I think the problem is here
```

thanks for any help

Comment: "Within context" is only *part* of the error message. There should be stuff above that line telling you what the actual error is, and stuff below that line telling you the context (i.e., the line number and function name).

Comment: Do you know that `Derived derived = *pderived;` calls the constructor `Derived::Derived(const Base& base)`?

Comment: Is this by any chance related to [non-scalar type requested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046463/non-scalar-type-requested/3046537#3046537)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access protected members from another object if that object is of the same type as the object that is trying to access it. In your example the constructor and assignment operator both take in a `const Base&` so there is no guarantee that the actual object will be of type `Derived`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error (VS2010)

`error C2248: 'Base::var' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'Base'`

at the line

`var=base.var;`

Comment: Right, because `base` might have type `class Other : public Base {};`.  `Derived` isn't in the inheritance chain for `Other`, so it has no access to protected members.

Answer (score 0):

`Derived` needs to delegate copying of `Base` members to `Base::operator=`, instead of trying to put its grubby little hands on the protected members of another object.