# an error within context

Tags: c++, class, oop

can somebody please explain my mistake, I have this class:

```
class Account
{
private:
    string strLastName;     
    string strFirstName;    
    int nID;              
    int nLines;             
    double lastBill;
public:
    Account(string firstName, string lastName, int id);
    friend string printAccount(string firstName, string lastName, int id, int lines, double lastBill);
}
```

but when I call it:

```
string reportAccounts() const
{
    string report(printAccountsHeader());
    for(list<Account>::const_iterator i = listOfAccounts.begin(); i != listOfAccounts.end(); ++i)
    {
        report += printAccount(i->strFirstName, i->strLastName, i->nID, i->nLines, i->lastBill);;
    }
        return report;
}
```

I receive error `within context`, can somebody explain why?

Comment: The error message is just "within context?"  Is this a run-time error or a compile-time error?  There's no other message?

Comment: Please heed the advice I gave you [last time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048809/error-in-c-within-context) and look at *the rest* of the error message. "Within context" is just a line that appears in the compiler output to *join* two other parts of the errors. Above it will be the actual error, and below it will be the name of the function the compiler was attempting to compile at the time. Take off your blinders and look at the bigger picture.

Comment: -1 for not posting the entire error.

Comment: Aside from suggesting that you provide the full error message in the future, I'd suggest you upvote answers that you like. As I write this, the accepted answer has no upvotes.  Voting takes 15 rep and as I write this you're showing 30:  click on the up arrow of at least the answer you accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I imagine the full error has something to do with "These members are private `within context`" and some line numbers.

The issue is that `i->strFirstName` is private from the perspective of the `reportAccounts()` function.  A better solution may be:

```
class Account{
    private:
        string strLastName;     
        string strFirstName;    
        int nID;              
        int nLines;             
        double lastBill;
    public:
        Account(string firstName, string lastName, int id);
        string print() const
        {
           return printAccount(this->strLastName, this->strFirstName, this->nID,
              this->nLines, this->lastBill);
        }
};
```

And then

```
string reportAccounts() const {
    string report(printAccountsHeader());
    for(list<Account>::const_iterator i = listOfAccounts.begin(); i != listOfAccounts.end(); ++i){
        report += i->print();
    }
    return report;
}
```

Another option is to make `printAccount` take a reference to an Account (`friend printAccount(const Account& account)`), and it can then access the private variables through the reference.

However, the fact that the function is called print **Account** suggests that it might be better as a public class function.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring that function `printAccount` is friend of `class Account`. But in the example, you're accessing the members of the class (`i->strFirstName` ...) in the function `reportAccounts`. This latter is not declared as friend.

Comment: In fact, thete's no reason for printAccount to be a friend the way you've written it. Better if you just pass printAccount a const Account& and let it pull out the values it needs. Or just make it a member function with no arguments, string print() const.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon in the class definition.

```
class Account{
    private:
        string strLastName;     
        string strFirstName;    
        int nID;              
        int nLines;             
        double lastBill;
    public:
        Account(string firstName, string lastName, int id);
    friend string printAccount(string firstName, string lastName, int id, int lines, double lastBill);
};
 ^--- see the semicolon here?
```

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be the whole error.. there should be something more..

by the way your friend syntax seems correct, but in `reportAccounts` you seem to use all the fields of `Account` class that are private, like `strFirstName` and the name of the function is `reportAccounts` not `printAccounts` so probably you just made a method friend but you are trying to access private fields with another one.